# Evaluating polynomials in modulo arithmetic

Tags: python, hash, modulo, polynomials

I need to repeatedly evaluate a polynomial of the form

f(x)=c(0)+c(1)*x+...+c(k-1)*x^(k-1) mod p

where k is an integer, p is a large prime number and c(0),...,c(p) are between 1 and p. 
For my applications, k=10, p should be greater than 1000.

I would prefer to do this in Python and as fast as possible. I don't know enough about modulo arithmetic in Python to implement this efficiently (e.g. how to exploit that we can use Mersenne primes p=2^q-1 in which case about should use that multiplication is a register shift, avoid trouble by adding integers over different orders of magnitude,...).

Motivation: k-independent hashing, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-independent_hashing. This seems to a very popular academic subject but I was not able to find any implementations for k>2.

Comment: you might have better luck asking about this on math.stackexchange.com/
 or mathematica.stackexchange.com then on stackoveflow

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#pow could be useful, it calculates x ** y % z by using exponentiation by squaring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you can compute the value of a polynomial using the following construction:

```
def value(poly, x):
  """Evaluates a polynomial POLY for a given x.

  The polynomial is expressed as a list of coefficients, with 
  the coefficient for x ** N at poly[N].

  This means that x ** 2 + 2*x + 3 is expressed as [3, 2, 1].
  """
  v = 0

  # Bit messy, but we're basically generating the indexes of 
  # our polynomial coefficients from highest to lowest
  for coeff in reverse(poly):
    v = v * x + coeff

  return v
```

To evaluate this modulo a value, we can simply change the inner loop to `v = v * x + poly[ix] % p` (and pass our modulus as the parameter p).

We can show that the example polynom (x^2 + 2x + 3) is computed correctly by unwinding the loop and see that what we have is `(((1) * x + 2) * x + 3)` (each parenthesis level is one iteration through the loop), this can be simplified to  1 * x * x + 2 * x + 3, which is clearly the expected polynomial.

By using this, we should never end up with an intermediate value larger than `p * x`.

Comment: You don't need the index; just iterate over the coefficients directly: `for coeff in reverse(poly): v = v*x + coff`.

Comment: Also, this is called [Horner's Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner%27s_method).

Comment: Thanks. I think this is called Horner scheme. However, I still believe one one should be able to further optimize, eg finite field arithmetic over GF(2^n) is enough (p can be a Mersenne prime).